# Is there a way to find already value or not in the field on Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to find,

- Is the field create or not? (empty)
- Is the filed has value or not?

**WITHOUT GETDATA(WITHOUT READ) THEN SETDATA**

```
 return _db.collection('users').document(id).setData({
        'createdAt':Timestamp.now()// If already value not insert
      }, merge: true);
```

*I hope you can understand my question because of my bad English*

Comment: You will have to query and read each document to determine if a field exists, then update it if it doesn't contain what you want.

Comment: it's mean there is no way to find without `getdata`. right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to check if a field exists in a document, or what its value is, is by reading that document. There is no way to do either of these actions without reading the document.

But if you want to ensure the `createdAt` only can get set once the document is created, you can do so in Firebase's server-side security rules.

For example:

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.createdAt == request.time
allow update: if request.resource.data.createdAt == resource.data.createdAt
```

This allows creating a document only if it has a `createdAt` field with its value being the server time. This means it must be set with `ServerValue.Timestamp()`. If you have a different business rule for the allowed value of `createdAt`, you can modify the rule as needed.

Once it's set when the document is created, the `createdAt` cannot be modified due to the `update` rule.

Comment: it's mean, we can't create a document without `setData({'createdAt'})`?